# MySQL returning result showing twice in while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a database named as ps_megasearch_attributes. For that my database query is like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_megasearch_attributes` (
  `attribute_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attribute_name` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`attribute_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8  ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `ps_megasearch_attributes`
--

INSERT INTO `ps_megasearch_attributes` (`attribute_id`, `attribute_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Color');
```

Now to get the values from the database I have this code in php

```
<?php 
$attribute_name_fetch = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `attribute_name` FROM `ps_megasearch_attributes` ORDER BY `attribute_id` DESC LIMIT 1 " );
while($attributes_list=mysqli_fetch_array($attribute_name_fetch )){
  foreach($attributes_list as $attribute_name) {
    echo $attribute_name;
  }
}

?>
```

But this one is showing the return result array two times. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this? Any help will be really appreciable.

Comment: No need for single quotes on column names and table names, that can make you query problems. Normally single quotes are only used for values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mysqli_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array)

> mysqli_result::fetch_array -- mysqli_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both

You don't require `foreach` loop.

```
while($attributes_list=mysqli_fetch_array($attribute_name_fetch )){
    echo $attributes_list['attribute_name']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 loops there - the while and foreach. Try:

```
<?php 
$attribute_name_fetch = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `attribute_name` FROM `ps_megasearch_attributes` ORDER BY `attribute_id` DESC LIMIT 1 " );
$attributes_list=mysqli_fetch_array($attribute_name_fetch);
foreach($attributes_list as $attribute_name) {
  echo $attribute_name;
}
?>
```